# Взаимодействие с свёнутыми(неактивными) окнами с возможностью параллельной работы с другими окнами в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Столкнулся с проблемой, решения которой нет ни на ютубе, ни в гугле. Дело в том, что существуют программы на python, которые способны автоматически взаимодействовать с клавиатурой и мышью на ПК, но я не нащёл возможности работы данных скриптов со свёрнутыми окнами. Также непонятно, как можно реализовать автоматизацию сразу нескольких свёрнутых окон с возможностью работы в другом окне (Целью является автоматическое нажатие клавиши в двух свёрнутых окнах игры и возможность в это время работы в текстовом редакторе или брузере без помех в работе браузера/текстового редактора)

---

**Решено!
В linux необходимо использовать xdotool для захвата окон и отправить в них нажатий мыши или клавиатуры(Естественно всё работает и со свёрнутыми\неактивными окнами). Для использования в python нужно использовать библиотеку os и работать с консолью(т.к. xdotool используется в консоли)**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Графический сервер собирает все события всех клавиатур и мышей в один поток и отправляет активному окну. Со свернутыми окнами работа не возможна, но..

В случае Linux на помощь приходит `XNest` и `Xephyr`. Это отдельный графический сервер который работает в отдельном окне. Если окно Xnest/Xephyr не активно, то в него не пересылаются сиганлы физических клавиатуры и мыши, но вполне работают `Virtual core XTEST pointer/keyboard` управляемые питоном.

```
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset :1 &
DISPLAY=:1 mutter &
DISPLAY=:1 xterm
```

Можно пойти дальше и обойтись без окон. Xspice, Xrdp и Xvnc создают виртуальный дисплей доступный удаленно по соответсвующему протоколу.

пс. Xephyr и Xspice поддерживают GL.

Comment: Решено! В linux необходимо использовать xdotool для захвата окон и отправить в них нажатий мыши или клавиатуры(Естественно всё работает и со свёрнутыми\неактивными окнами). Для использования в python нужно использовать библиотеку os и работать с консолью(т.к. xdotool используется в консоли)

Comment: xdotool это другое)

Answer (score 0):

Решено! В linux необходимо использовать xdotool для захвата окон и отправить в них нажатий мыши или клавиатуры(Естественно всё работает и со свёрнутыми\неактивными окнами). Для использования в python нужно использовать библиотеку os и работать с консолью(т.к. xdotool используется в консоли)